How do i check if a cell value is smaller than 2 other cells and highlight the first
I have a specific problem I would like to solve. I would like to highlight cells in the N column if the K and/or L columns in the same row are a larger value. L is not always filled, but if necessary I could make it so it is.

i've tried getting conditional formatting to work with no luck yet.

Welcome to SO.  if the K and/or L columns Please, notice AND vs OR is a totally different approach. Make sure you use the right choice. Please read Use AND and OR to test a combination of conditions. Clarify that part, please

Entered in cell N2 and applied to $N$2:$N$x (where x is the last row of data):
=AND($N2<>"",OR($K2>$N2, $L2>$N2))

